# how to set a hstore value in rails from json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to set a hstore value `feed_states` in rails however I am having some trouble. It is saving the json, however I wanted it to serialize the json and save it as an array.

```
def save_feed
  if params[:feed]
    feedItems = params[:feed]
    current_user.update_attribute(:feed_states, {feed: feedItems})
  end

  render json: {}
end
```

The json being sent to the endpoint `params[:conversations]` is just an object with an array of valyes e.g.

```
{ feed: ['123, '321'] }
```

Comment: i think you need strong params for this

Comment: Agree, you'll need strong params. Though, can you be more specific on the error/issue you're having?

Comment: I will update the question now it is working but it is saving as json not as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like hstores in rails only save as strings, so I have to save it as a json string, then use JSON.parse on the client.